# python 2.7.6 printing a list containing five strings using loops

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list and my professor wants us to print it using loops. How the heck do i do this?

```
plants = 'apples,  beans,  carrots , dates , eggplant'
for i in list(plants):
    print plants
```

here is the code that I'm working with. What do i need to fix? I get fifty lines of the list when I do it this way.

Edit:

Forgot to add the final step. It needs to print out this before the list:
'The items in the list are: ' How would I do this? I am doing this:

```
print 'The items in the list are: ' + plant
```

This is based off of Martijn Pieters's answer.
sorry for the confusion

The expected outcome is this:

The items in the list are:

apples beans carrots dates eggplant

Comment: That's not a list, that's a single string.

Comment: Well, for one thing you want to `print i` in the loop body, but you're looping over the characters in a string.

Comment: If you have a string you might want to [split](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) it.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to make a `list` from what you have. As it is now, `plants` is a `string`, and when you iterate over it, you get one character at a time. You can convert this string to a list using `split`.

```
>>> plants = 'apples,  beans,  carrots , dates , eggplant'.split(', ')
>>> plants
['apples', ' beans', ' carrots ', 'dates ', 'eggplant']
>>> for plant in plants:
    print plant
apples
beans
carrots
dates
eggplant
```

Answer (score 2):

You have *one* string, containing text with commas in them. This would be a list of strings:

```
plants = ['apples', 'beans', 'carrots', 'dates', 'eggplant']
```

and your loop would look like:

```
for plant in plants:
    print plant
```

Your code instead looped over the individual characters of the input string:

```
>>> list('apples,  beans,  carrots , dates , eggplant')
['a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', 's', ',', ' ', ' ', 'b', 'e', 'a', 'n', 's', ',', ' ', ' ', 'c', 'a', 'r', 'r', 'o', 't', 's', ' ', ',', ' ', 'd', 'a', 't', 'e', 's', ' ', ',', ' ', 'e', 'g', 'g', 'p', 'l', 'a', 'n', 't']
```

You could also split on those commas, and remove the extra whitespace from the result with:

```
plants = 'apples,  beans,  carrots , dates , eggplant'
for plant in plants.split(','):
     print plant.strip()
```